# Node.js failed to load resource

Tags: sql, node.js, sqlite

I've been working with node.js with sqlite3 database. Below is one of my endpoints to get data from the database.

```
app.get('/newGame', async (req, res) => {
  try {
    let name = req.query.name;
    let size = req.query.size;

    let db = await getDBConnection();
    let insertGameQry = 'INSERT INTO games (winner_id) VALUES (null);';
    let insertGameResult = await db.run(insertGameQry);
    let gameId = insertGameResult.lastID;
    res.json({'game_id': gameId});
  } catch (err) {
    res.type('text');
    res.status(SERVER_ERROR).send(SERVER_ERROR_MSG);
  }
}
```

I first get the two query params from the request and connect to the database by `getDBConnection()`, and then insert a null value to `winner_id` of the table `games` (since there's still not a winner), and thus get the `gameId` in the same table  which auto increments by using `lastID`. However, I constantly get a server 500 error when I clicked the corresponding button at the client side. I've included all the dependencies and confirmed to have the correct project structure and a `.db` file. Is there any way to get where the problem is? I've also tried to `console.log` the query parameters in google DevTool and it works fine. However, when I  `console.log` the `gameId`, it prints nothing on the console. Can anybody provides a method for debugging?

Comment: You should print the `err` in your catch method, so you will have a clue of what is happening. If you would like to see where the error happens, I would suggest removing the try ... catch clause. (only for debugging purpose). After you fix the bug, you can put it back.

Comment: Is the winner_id nullable? If it isn't then inserting a null value would definitely cause the problem. Like @Danizavtz said, print the `err` would definitely help clear that.

Comment: Printing the err means "console.log(err)", right?

Comment: The error got printed is:

[Error: SQLITE_BUSY: database is locked] {
  errno: 5,
  code: 'SQLITE_BUSY'
}

Answer (score 0):

Check your sqlite3 database schema to see if `winner_id` has `NOT NULL` set.

Comment: It does not have NOT NULL set. Actually I solved this problem first time because I ignored the quote around the database file. Then I edit some of my codes and delete them and the problem occurs again, which is strange.